# Can you help re-tag some untagged posts?

Tags: discussion, retagging

I'm working rather hard to try to clean up tags so that everyone stands a better chance of seeing the types of questions that interest them. This is something I've been doing behind the scenes for a while, but occasionally I'm running into stuff where I could use some help from better experts.

We've got around 100 [untagged](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions, most of which are an artifact of the migrations from the former AVP site to here. They need tags, preferably two where applicable. They're getting churned a bit, but we're not catching them.

These need a tag, ideally two if more could apply, so that people can actually *find* them in tag searches and not trip over them due to tag filters not spotting them. Of course, if they aren't good questions - edit if you can, flag if they aren't salvageable.

If you've got a few minutes, have a look at some and edit or suggest edits to improve the tag, don't forget to drop 'untagged' once you've applied a better tag.

Many many thanks :)

Comment: did about 10, still about 160 left though..

Comment: I'm working on these too, thanks for the flags!

Comment: The downside is that we'll be messing up the front page for a bit, but at least we'll end up in a better place, and maybe find some of them which can just be deleted.